# Merge all active values in rows into single column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have the above formatted table.

I want to merge all last values in every row under a single column "Last Cell".

Could somebody please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this formula in your table's last column.

```
=IF(MOD(COUNTA(Table1[@[IN]:[OUT4]]),2),"",INDEX(Table1[@[IN]:[OUT4]],1,COUNTA(Table1[@[IN]:[OUT4]])))
```

The term `Table1[@[IN]:[OUT4]]` appears 3 times. It specifies the range from the `IN` column to `OUT4` column in `Table1`. Change the table name to match the name of your table. You can also specify a sheet range, like A2:H2.

The formula returns nothing (blank) if the last used column is an `IN` column and the value in that column if it's an `OUT` column. The column is identified by the MOD() function. `MOD(COUNTA(Table1[@[IN]:[OUT4]]),2)` will either return 1 or 0. `IF(MOD(COUNTA(Table1[@[IN]:[OUT4]]),2),"",` will return a blank if the result is 1. If you have columns to the left of what you showed us, and need to include them in the range examined by the formula, you may have to change this part of the formula into `IF(MOD(COUNTA(Table1[@[IN]:[OUT4]]),2)=0,"",` to omit results if the last column is an `IN` column.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is CONCATENATE which means to merge the data together.

You can use 
`=CONCATENATE(cell1, " ", cell2)`

-- OR --

The less 'codey' way of doing this is to merge the data without using the `=CONCATENATE()` formula: `=A1&" "&A2&" "&A3&" "...` etc